# Debugging Settings for openCV project on VisualStudio 2013 [x64 machine]

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, visual-studio-2013, settings

My computer is x64bit so when setting the libraries and headers i would pass through opencv/build/x64/.. directory

it would say there are build errors and output the following in the terminal

Error   1   error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'   C:\Users\koda\Desktop\FacialDetection\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\opencv_highgui2410.lib(opencv_highgui2410.dll)    ConsoleApplication2

i so changed all of the settings to opencv/build/x86/.. and didn't get errors in the code

trying to debug, a window appears saying that it's impossible to start the program because "opencv_highgui2410.dll" is missing in th computer. i assured that i was importing this file when importing the .lib files imported in both PropertySheet_Release and _Debug > Linker>Input

in the IDE's terminal the output i get these error messages 'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. The program '[7084] ConsoleApplication2.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.

but checking in the directory i find those files..

what should i do to get the code working?

thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: ***what should i do to get the code working?*** Make sure you have the correct libraries and binaries for the compiler and configuration you want to target your application. Do not mix debug and release. Do not mix 32 and 64 bit. Do not use libraries or dlls from some other version of Visual Studio. Remember that Visual Studio 2013 is vc12 (not vc13).

Comment: thanks for your reply. i did not know that visual studio 13 was vc 12!
what do you mean by not mixing the debug and release? i always put the same file when setting up the first and the latter. is it wrong?

Comment: ***what do you mean by not mixing the debug and release?*** Do not use debug libraries/dlls for release applications or release libraries for debug applications. In opencv debug libs and dlls will have a d before .lib and .dll. Release will not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy "opencv_highgui2410**d**.dll" from *opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin* to your Debug folder and "opencv_highgui2410.dll" to your Release folder (where the executables are located).

You might need to do it as well with "opencv_core2410.dll" and "opencv_imgproc2410.dll".

By the way, you can cannot import a DLL from the linker, that's the main goal of a DLL (being 'dynamic', compared to static LIBs).

Comment: thank you for your reply, should i use ../x86 or ../x64 directories? i ask this because when setting up with x64 dir i get error LNK1112 machine type x64 conflicts with machine type x86...i don't really understand why i get this error since im sure my compter is x64

Comment: In your situation, I suggest you to use /x86 directories. By default, Visual Studio is targeting a 32 bit application (despite the fact your computer supports 64 bit applications). Usually, for simplicity, you should always target a 32 bit application if it is not meant to be a commercial product or a really big project.

Comment: also i don't see a relase folder. in the directory of the project the only folder i see is degub.

Comment: That's fine. That's because you never compiled your solution in Release. Anyway, you should stick to Debug for now.

Comment: okay i've now set everything as you said (../x86 dir and opencv_highgui2410d.dll in the debug folder) but i still get an error window claiming that opencv_highgui2410(WITHNOD).dll is not in the computer

Comment: 'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\koda\Desktop\FacialDetection\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: Did you link "opencv_highgui2410d.lib" (with a 'd') from opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib or you linked the Release lib (without a 'd')?

Comment: i've copied both of them just to be sure ;)

Comment: Don't do this. In your linker's inputs, if you are running a Debug configuration (your case), import only the ones with a 'd' suffix. Importing both generates conflicts between libs.

Comment: sorry for continuing and tamper you but i really can't get this working..
i removed the opencv_highgui2410.lib that i was importing in linker>input but im still getting the same errorr..

Comment: Try the following: Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and select checkbox "Microsoft Symbol Servers".

Comment: Then you probably have a wrong path setup somewhere. See http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+find+or+open+the+pdb+file.